# Disable system/combo bar Android ICS with out rooting

Tags: android

I have searched high and low, all the while people telling me that, "no it is impossible to completely surpress the navigation/combo bar on an ICS tablet without rooting it.. and then i find there is an app on the market called Surelock that does exactly this..  Unfortunately i am building a launcher app myself so i can't use their launcher app, but the big question is HOW do they do it?  anyone?

Comment: I accept answers that work.. if you look you'll find all the answers I have not accepted were not resolutions

Comment: Did you discovery how they do that? I think they use reflection to call hide methods.

Comment: can try this to disable system bar, except home. [disable system bar][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15049273/hide-home-button-disable-right-side-options-from-system-bar/15470716#15470716

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever SureLock is doing is exploiting some security hole. Someday, I will take the time to find out what they are doing and will work to get the hole fixed.

Comment: They are not the only ones doing it.. I'm trying to build an app that won't be on the market and is for letting a tablet in kiosk type mode, where we find the ability to get to system settings with out a password a security risk