# Hide Home button & disable right side options from system bar

Tags: android, android-layout, mobile, android-activity, lockscreen

I have found non rooted apps which are capable of hide home button from bottom system bar of tabs (not all the devices but many of samsung tabs) & disabling (not hiding) right side wifi, settings entering panel in system bar (worked in all the testing devices). Good example is remote lock screen of Lookout premium app with BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN permission. This lock screen appears on top of the native android lock screen  it has these features work in many devices.

Is there a way to create an activity with disabling System bar like that? Is it related to the flag that adding to the layout params of the activity? Otherwise how this is implemented?

Thanks.

Comment: It is "implemented" by exploiting security flaws that I am working on getting fixed. Moreover, it is no longer necessary as of Android 4.2, at least for standard Android UIs (e.g., Nexus tablets): http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/02/20/android-4p2-for-kiosk-apps.html

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare. Yours answers are direct & helpful in many ways. But I would like to clarify according to your post, if we need a kiosk app, we need to go for a home app in 4.2+ android os which leverages for Kiosk. I see that is one good option even right now also if you want Kiosk. So what you are saying is inside Android API, there is no way to hide home icon or disable right side setting launcher menu in system bar of tabs?

Comment: "So what you are saying is inside Android API, there is no way to hide home icon or disable right side setting launcher menu in system bar of tabs?" -- you cannot permanently hide the system bar/navigation bar on tablets, and you cannot disable anything there. You can "disable" the HOME button by making your app be the home screen.